# "Launching AssertionViolatedException" in java

Tags: java, eclipse

I'm having a problem in Eclipse, I was going to launch a project and it appeared a window that tells me the following:

> "Launching AssertionViolatedException" has encountered a problem.
>
> Launch configuration AssertionViolatedException references
>   non-existing project Scraping_with_Selenium.

Scraping_with_Selenium is a project I had and I wasn't using. I have deleted it but with no result at all. I have also tried re-installing eclipse but keeps not running...what is happening?

Comment: Seems like this is referenced in your workspace. Try to clean that up or use a new workspace.

Comment: `Run As -> Java Application` will help you...

Comment: @Thomas Worked!

Answer (score 0):

When changing the project workspace the issue("Launching AssertionViolatedException" has encountered a problem.) is fixed for me.

Eclipse,  Selenium 3.4

Comment: Please give more details about your coding environment (e.g. what IDE are you using?) that way, we can properly help you. Also, are there any other error logs that are shown?